# Using Algebraic Data Type to combine lists

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

I'm trying to understand the syntax of created algebraic data types. The type I've created is either an `[Int]` or `Empty`, similar to `Maybe` with `Just` and `Nothing` except the `Just` has to be a list of `Int`. I'm having trouble understanding manipulating the created type when it accepts two inputs and gives an output of the same type.

```
data Example = Arg [Int]
         | Empty
    deriving Show
```

I use pattern matching and understand that every case must be addressed; however, my issue comes from the syntax of the final pattern where neither is `Empty`. I'm trying to write two functions: one that combines both `[Int]` lists from the `Example` constructor, and I want to create a function that only shows a set of `[Int]` that both share, instead of combining.

The first issue is combining two sets. I can do it in a normal function but somewhere, using the `Example` data type, the syntax is off and I'm unfamiliar with it. The biggest issue in the second is the same: I understand recursion but I don't understand the syntax of recursion in a created data type. I was also thinking of using a `where` statement in the second function but if I can't get the syntax of basic recursion right then I doubt it'd be successful.

```
combine :: Example -> Example -> Example
combine Empty Empty = Empty
combine (Arg xs) Empty = (Arg xs)
combine Empty (Arg ys) = (Arg ys)
combine (Arg xs) (Arg ys) = Arg xs ++ ys

same :: Example -> Example -> Example
same _ Empty = Empty
same Empty _ = Empty
same (Arg x : xs) (Arg y : ys)
  | x == y    = x
  | otherwise = same (Arg xs) (Arg ys)
```

The output of `combine` should be an `[Int]` list containing all `Int`s from both lists; if one list is empty, it should return the entire set of the non-empty list.

The output of `same` should contain an `[Int]` list containing only the numbers shared by both groups, with no repeats; if one set is empty, the output is empty.

Comment: The only problem I've noticed (unable to test right now) is that the outputs of the functions should use the `Arg` constructor - eg. the first 2 cases for `combine` should result in `Arg []`

Comment: oh, and there are some more problems in the `same` function. `Arg x : xs` should be `Arg (x : xs)`. You've not covered the case where either argument is `Arg []`. And (in the `x == y` guard in the final pattern) you can't have `x` as the output.

Comment: And in trying to make sense of what the `same` function might be intended to do - is there supposed to be a difference in "meaning" between `Arg []` and `Empty`? And if so, what is it?

Comment: you're missing the parens in the last line of `combine`. to pass the type checker, it should be `... = Arg (xs ++ ys)`. it won't be right (in case you want to not include the duplicate elements in the result), but at least it'll type check. --- `same (Arg x : xs) (Arg y : ys) = ...` is wrong too: it should be `same (Arg (x : xs)) (Arg (y : ys)) = ...`

Comment: you have many questions all jumbled up in one post. you will have better ROI if you ask a specific, well-focused question, with/about *one* code snippet. i.e. the minimal code, as in [mcve]. but it turns out that my previous comment answers your new edit. you just need to add parens around the `(x:xs)` inside the `(Arg (x:xs))` etc., because what you have now is interpreted as `(Arg x) : xs`.

Comment: general advice: while still learning the basics, use explicit parens *everywhere*. forget about `$`. even use the explicit `{ ; }` in `let`, `case` and `do` (with a proper code indentation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the concept of [lifting](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lifting), I came ou with this solution:

```
import Data.List (nub)

data Example = Arg [Int]
         | Empty
    deriving Show

combine :: Example -> Example -> Example
combine Empty Empty = Empty
combine x Empty = x
combine Empty x = x
combine (Arg xs) (Arg ys) = Arg $ nub $ xs ++ ys

same :: Example -> Example -> Example
same arg1 arg2 = lift nub $ same' arg1 arg2
    where
        same' _ Empty = Empty
        same' Empty _ = Empty
        same' (Arg []) y = Arg []
        same' (Arg (x : xs)) (Arg (ys))
            | x `elem` ys = lift (x : ) $ same' (Arg xs) (Arg ys)
            | otherwise  = same' (Arg xs) (Arg ys)

lift :: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> Example -> Example
lift _ Empty = Empty
lift f (Arg x) = Arg (f x)
```

What `lift` do is to apply a function to the "content" of `Arg`. If you have the expression `same (Arg [1, 2, 4, 3]) (Arg [3,1,4])` the recursion will turn it into:

```
lift nub $ lift (1 : ) $ lift (4 : ) $ lift (3 : ) $ Arg []
```

wich evaluates like:

```
lift nub $ lift (1 : ) $ lift (4 : ) $ Arg (3:[])
lift nub $ lift (1 : ) $ Arg (4:3:[])
lift nub $ Arg (1:4:3:[])
Arg (nub $ 1:4:3:[])
```

then finally:

```
Arg [1,4,3]
```

Comment: Note that `lift` is similar to `omap` from the `mono-traversable` package.

Comment: @WillNess You were right, thank you. Edited the code to eliminate all the extra `nub`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
combine :: Example -> Example -> Example
combine x Empty = x
combine Empty x = x
combine (Arg xs) (Arg ys) = Arg $ union xs ys

union xs ys = nub $ xs ++ ys
nub [] = []
nub (x:xs) = if x `elem` xs then nub xs else x : nub xs

same :: Example -> Example -> Example
same _ Empty = Empty
same Empty _ = Empty
same (Arg xs) (Arg ys) = Arg $ intersect xs ys

intersect _ [] = [] -- unnecessary but practical!
intersect [] _ = []
intersect (x:xs) ys = if x `elem` ys then x : intersect xs ys else intersect xs ys
```

As Robin comments, you have a couple of different issues. Firstly you need to match all the cases, secondly you need to wrap the results back up into your data type, thirdly you need to remove duplicates in the union, fourthly your "set intersection" operation would only work with some very strong assumptions about the structure of the input lists. `union`, `intersect` (also available in Data.List) are good enough for demonstration purposes without invoking eg. `Data.IntSet.toList . Data.IntSet.fromList` although that would be faster. Your version (if corrected slightly) would output the elements that appear in at the same position in both lists.

Common tutorials on functors often start with the `Maybe` kind, that might be helpful for you in understanding this because `Example` is isomorphic to `Maybe [Int]`.

An example where you might want to use the `Arg (x : xs)` deconstructor would be a function that takes the lesser element at each index from the two lists. Could you try writing that yourself recursively ie. without using `zip`?

EDIT: heavy changes and corrections

Comment: Corrected `combine` to your spec. It's a bit unnatural, because usually `Empty` does something different to `Arg []`. `nub` takes a list and removes duplicate entries. `$` is function application and I used it here to remove the need for brackets; `a $ b c = a (b c)` and `a $ b $ c = a (b (c))`. The problem with writing `same` recursively is that you essentially need to sort the lists to do it, but I can write another version 1 sec.

Comment: 1) you're a god, thank you. 2) instead of `$` I can substitute `[]`? 3) thank you again, this is saving my life. I've been pulling my hair out trying to understand algebraic data type syntax. I understand the idea and pattern matching but get caught in the syntax.

Comment: 2) No you cannot, they are completely different! You should fire up GHCi and play with them. The :t command tells you something's type and is very useful.

Comment: I got the `combine` to work but I'm still having issues with using recursion on `same` to return a list of [Int] with only like Ints and no repeats.

Comment: 3) the easiest way to learn is to try. Look at the error messages when you try to compile it, try to understand what the compiler is objecting to, and search the errors for beginners with similar problems and see what people said. Error messages are never perfectly informative, but learning to read them is invaluable for understanding where one's code is wrong.

Comment: It is legitimately syntax. The correct answer for `combine` was just `()` in a place that I hadn't tried yet, which always seems the case for me in haskell. I'm always missing some parenthesis.

Comment: I wrote same' and added it above. It's how I'm most comfortable in the syntax, using guards and a where statement instead of the local `let`. I'm a beginner and I'm trying to stay within what I know well. The error seems to come from the where statement as not being recognized but it's probably because of mismatched parenthesis or syntax.

Comment: `same a b = nub (a++b)` is wrong. `same` is supposed to be set intersection, according to the description in the question. `nub` belongs in `combine`, which is supposed to be a union.

Comment: Ah you're totally right, fixed it. That's what comes from doing everything without testing!

Comment: the pattern `(Arg x : xs)` is wrong, missing some parens inside.

Comment: May I ask one final question: why does your intersect not need a type definition?

Comment: It's good practice to give top-level functions type definitions (and if you ask the compiler to warn you about anything potentially bad, this is one of things it'll mention), but often unnecessary. Here the compiler sees eg. pattern matching on lists for the left argument, and that the right argument is passed as the second argument to `elem`, so both arguments must be lists. Likewise they must be lists of the same type supporting equality because of the call to `elem`. Hence `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`. Search Hindley-Milner. PS sorry for any confusion from my mistakes, answering on mobile!